# EventLog Windows Event - Why is event #6008 logged even after normal shutdown and restart?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, eventviewer, shutdown, unexpected-shutdown

I have been restarting and shutting down the machine through proper steps, ie, using start button, using command line and using Alt+F4. But, shut down event tracker is not logging any events. On windows start-up, EventLog is registering error #6008 with message: 
   'The previous system shutdown at on was unexpected.' 
Can anyone please help me with troubleshooting this issue or provide possible causes?

Comment: What windows version do you use?

Comment: @boboes I use Windows 10.